# Implement "Catch Block" like behavior in Spring using AOP

Tags: spring, exception, spring-aop

I'm working on Spring application and I want to implement exception handling in following way:
Implement an Aspect class for specific exception type where that exception is diverted
Have such aspect classes based on exception types hierarchy and implement catch block like behavior 
for example,
there're two aspect classes: ExceptionHandler for Exception and SQLExceptionHandler for SQLException
Both of them are exactly same pointcut expression.
Now, if SQLException is raised from any method which is covered in point expression, SQLExceptionHandler's method should be executed.
If FileNotFoundException or any other type of exception occurs then ExceptionHandler's method should be executed.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is too broad a question. And looks like an assignment. But to give an idea : you could implement a `BeanPostProcessor` that will wrap your annotated classes with an invocation handler wrapping the method invocation in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending the `OncePerRequestFilter` class and overriding the `doFilterInternal` method. Something like following will do the trick:

```
    public void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ExceptionType1 e) { 
    // Any exception thrown from your code can be handled or retrhown from here.
    } catch (ExceptionType2 e) { 
    // Any exception thrown from your code can be handled or retrhown from here.
    } catch ......
}
```